# Get exe with Pyinstaller including pygubu

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pygubu

I would like to generate a portable python application, which i can share to my colleagues.

I used pygubu to create a tkinter GUI and would like to genereate a exe file with pyinstall.

After the `pyinstaller PythonAppGUI.py` command I get an exe.
If I run the exe a command window pops-up for a second and closed ifself.

Is there any solution how i can use the pygubu-module with the pyinstaller. All other provided soltion on the internet are not really helpfull.

Thanks a lot.

My python-template-code with which i am trying to generate a exe.
In the same folder is the **pyapp.ui**-file for the GUI

```
import tkinter as tk
import pygubu


class Menu:
 
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master=master
        #Create builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()
        #Load ui file
        builder.add_from_file('pyapp.ui')
        #Create a widget, using master as a parent
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('mainframe', master)

        #Connect callbacks
        builder.connect_callbacks(self)
    
    def but1(self):
        pass

    def but2(self):
        pass
    
               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Start Menu GUI
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Menu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller may not be adding `pyapp.ui` to the directory automatically, try;

```
pyinstaller --add-data "pyapp.ui;." PythonAppGUI.py
```

the command copies `pyapp.ui` to the root directoy of the executable where i believe `PythonAppGUI.py` is exepecting it to be

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't open the GUI. When I do a right click on the PythonAppGUI.py-file and open it with "Python" I get the same behavoir. It seems to work only with the "python PythonAppGUI.py build" command. What am I still missing with Pygubu?

Comment: Have you tried `app.run()` instead of `root.mainloop()`?

Comment: Yes i tried that as well: 
                 

`app = Menu()
    app.run()`

Comment: for some reason pyinstaller is not adding pygubu into the executable, I've tried using `--hidden-import pygubu` with no success

Comment: I've looked into it but I have had no success, if I find any information that works I shall let you know